# Renaming of emails in g-suite

Tags: email, google-workspace

I renamed an email address in the g-suite admin portal. Funny enough, the old address still appears when someone wants to send an email to that person. What did I miss when renaming it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this contact is saved on each users email address, also remember than when you rename a user the old username becomes an alias for the user to keep receiving emails to the old email address.

If you don't want anyone to send emails to this person to the old email you have to delete the email alias, however, this old email may not be removed from each users contacts information for being personal information, they should delete it from their contacts.

You can check this help center article from Google for more details https://support.google.com/a/answer/182084?hl=en. look for "If you change their email address..." I hope this helps, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

If you change their e-mail address an alias is automatically created for the old address.

Additionally, users who have corresponded with the person previously will find an auto-complete entry in their [individual contact list](https://contacts.google.com/other).  If you need it gone from your managed users's auto-complete lists, you can sweep these locations with [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)